# Getting unsupported charset \"ISO-8859-1\ error in rest assured post call

Tags: rest, testng, rest-assured, testng-dataprovider

I was trying to make a post call using Best Buy api playground, I wrote usual code to make post call in rest assured however I am getting 500 error unsupported charset "ISO-8859-1. I am using data provider class to pass json payload to post call

Here is swagger API docs
[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

here is the console logs:-

```
2021-06-18 11:48:15 INFO  BestBuy Rest API:29 - ----Create new product request test started----
2021-06-18 11:48:16 INFO  BestBuy Rest API:57 - The response for create product
{
    "name": "GeneralError",
    "message": "unsupported charset \"ISO-8859-1\"",
    "code": 500,
    "className": "general-error",
    "data": {
        
    },
    "errors": {
        
    }
}
2021-06-18 11:48:16 INFO  BestBuy Rest API:36 - ----Create new product request test completed

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

here is the code for post call

```
public class TC002_BestBuy_CreateProduct extends TestBase{

    private static String prodID;

    public static String getVariable(){
        return prodID;
    }

    public static void setVariable(String var){
        prodID = var;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void createProductData(){
        logger.info("----Create new product request test started----");

        TestBase.initialization();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
        logger.info("----Create new product request test completed");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1,dataProvider = "apiDataProvider",dataProviderClass = APIDataProvider.class,description = "post call and status check for create product")
    public void createProduct(String name,String type,String price,String shipping,String upc,String description,String manufacturer,String model,String url,String image){

        TestBase.response= given()
                .baseUri(property.getProperty("BaseURI"))
                .queryParam("name",name)
                .queryParam("type",type)
                .queryParam("price",price)
                .queryParam("shipping",shipping)
                .queryParam("upc",upc)
                .queryParam("description",description)
                .queryParam("manufacturer",manufacturer)
                .queryParam("model",model)
                .queryParam("url",url)
                .queryParam("image",image)
                .post(property.getProperty("createProductURL"));


        logger.info("The response for create product");
        TestBase.response.prettyPrint();

        String productId=TestBase.response.jsonPath().get("id");
        setVariable(productId);

    }
  }
```

Here is the code for excel utility class to read excel data

```
public static int getRowCount(String xlfile,String xlsheet) throws IOException
    {
        fi=new FileInputStream(xlfile);
        wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
        ws=wb.getSheet(xlsheet);
        int rowcount=ws.getLastRowNum();
        wb.close();
        fi.close();
        return rowcount;
    }


    public static int getCellCount(String xlfile,String xlsheet,int rownum) throws IOException
    {
        fi=new FileInputStream(xlfile);
        wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
        ws=wb.getSheet(xlsheet);
        row=ws.getRow(rownum);
        int cellcount=row.getLastCellNum();
        wb.close();
        fi.close();
        return cellcount;
    }


    public static String getcellData(String sheetname, int rowNum, int colNum) {

        row = ws.getRow(rowNum);
        cell = row.getCell(colNum);
        int index = wb.getSheetIndex(sheetname);

        if (rowNum <= 0) {
            return "";
        } else if (index == -1) {
            return "";
        } else if (cell == null) {
            return "";
        } else if (row == null) {
            return "";
        } else if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        } else if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC || cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA) {
            String cellValue = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
                Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
                cellValue = df.format(date);
            }
            return cellValue;
        } else if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK) {
            return "";
        } else return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
    }


    public static void setCellData(String xlfile,String xlsheet,int rownum,int colnum,String data) throws IOException
    {
        fi=new FileInputStream(xlfile);
        wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
        ws=wb.getSheet(xlsheet);
        row=ws.getRow(rownum);
        cell=row.createCell(colnum);
        cell.setCellValue(data);
        fo=new FileOutputStream(xlfile);
        wb.write(fo);
        wb.close();
        fi.close();
        fo.close();
    }
}
```

here is the data provider class to supply data after reading from excel

```
public class APIDataProvider {

    @DataProvider(name = "apiDataProvider")
    public Object[][] getEmpData() throws IOException {

        String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/TestResources/TestData.xlsx";
        int row=ExcelUtils.getRowCount(path,"Sheet1");
        int col=ExcelUtils.getCellCount(path,"Sheet1",1);

        String empdata[][]=new String[row][col];

        for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                empdata[i - 1][j] = ExcelUtils.getcellData("Sheet1", i, j);
            }
        }
      return (empdata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see on swagger that request is POST, not Get, so you should change the how to setup API call: change queryParam --> post body.
Read more: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#request-body.
Example:

```
@Test
void demo() {
    BestBuyProduct aProduct = new BestBuyProduct();
    aProduct.setName("apple");
    aProduct.setType("fruit");
    aProduct.setPrice(30);
    aProduct.setShipping(30);
    aProduct.setUpc("DF400");
    aProduct.setDescription("test");
    aProduct.setManufacturer("XYZ");
    aProduct.setModel("AB123");
    aProduct.setUrl("http://example");
    aProduct.setImage("/apple.img");
    
   given().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
           .body(aProduct)
           .post("to_your_api_endpoint");
}
```

To convert from POJO --> json, don't forget to add jackson or gson to classpath.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Btw, instead of using Apache POI directly, you can use https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji to convert excel --> POJO.
It will help reduce the complex of reading excel file and decrease the number of parameter for test case also.